# Почему не вызывается конструктор родителя?

Tags: php, ооп

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo 'ok';
    }
}

class B {
    protected $var;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->var = $a;
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public function __invoke() {
        $this->var->foo();
    }
}

$var = new C(new A);
$var();
```

Получаю:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: C::$var in /var/www/.../q.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function foo() on null in /var/www/.../q.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/.../q.php(22): C->__invoke()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/.../q.php on line 17
```

Раньше когда C и B были одним классом все работало.
Тут я так понял не то что не вызывается конструктор, а даже не наследуется $var, почему?

Comment: `private` на `protected` сменить не желаете?

Comment: Точно, но не чего не изменилось. При public разумеется тоже

Comment: Что значит не изменилось? Добавил я в конструктор родителя строку `echo "dddddd";` на экране увидел текст `ddddddok`, то есть конструктор родителя выполняется.

Comment: Да, работает, а не работало ибо надо не `new A`, а `new A()`.

Comment: Работает именно так: `$var = new C(new A);`

Comment: Да, действительно. Значит это я где-то зарукожопил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo 'ok';
    }
}

class B {
    protected $var;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->var = $a;
    }
}

class C extends B {

    public function __invoke() {
        $this->var->foo();
    }
}



$var = new C(new A());

$var();
```

Comment: И что, мне в каждом классе(которых у меня не мало) вручную конструктор вызывазь?

Comment: Согласно синтаксиса PHP конструктор родителя необходимо вызывать явно http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Конструкторы в классах-родителях не вызываются автоматически, если класс-потомок определяет собственный конструктор, иначе наследуется и соотвецтвенно должен вызывается.

Comment: Да вы правы, щас исправим